# Embedding TTF in SVG doesn't work in SVG markers but in Layout text items

Tags: qgis, svg, font

In my desparate aim to put everything inside a Geopackage file (mainly for use with the wonderful "input" app), I came across the situation where I wanted to store font files (TTF) inside my QGIS project.

While searching the Web, I found the SVG @font-face declaration which allows to embed base64 encoded truetype fonts:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2048 2048">
<defs>
  <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: "myfont";
        src: url("data:appllication/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,AAEAAAAPAIAAAwBwT1MvM ... NUjAwAAAAAAAA") format('truetype');
    }
  </style>
</defs>
<g>
  <text fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" x="1024" y="2048" font-size="2048" font-family="myfont" text-anchor="middle" xml:space="preserve">F</text>
 </g>
</svg>
```

This works like a charm in Layout text items, but unfortunately not in SVG markers.
Can someone explain why SVG markers refuse to read the style declaration here?

P.S. I‘m using QGIS 3.16.3 on Windows